# Build openjdk7 on Ubuntu 12.04 with a error

Tags: java, linux

Im try to build openjdk 7 hotspot on Ubuntu 12.04,these is my build.sh

#### build.sh start

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=C

export ALT_BOOTDIR=/home/jdk1.6.0_45

export ALT_JDK_IMPORT_PATH=/home/jdk1.6.0_45

export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.8.4

export PATH="/usr/lib/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/ usr/games:/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.8.4:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6"

export HOTSPOT_BUILD_JOBS=5

export ALT_OUTPUTDIR=/home/jdk1.7

cd make
make jvmg jvmg1 2>&1 | tee $ALT_OUTPUTDIR/build.log
```

#### build.sh end

and then The Building was success, and output blow messages:

#### output start

```
cd linux_i486_compiler1/jvmg && ./test_gamma

java full version "1.6.0_45-b06"

java version "1.6.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)

OpenJDK Client VM (build 21.0-b17-internal-jvmg, mixed mode)

1. A1 B5 C8 D6 E3 F7 G2 H4

...

Using java runtime at: /home/jdk1.6.0_45/jre

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jdk1.7'
```

#### output end

My Question is why is the building jvm becomes to jdk1.6.0_45('build.sh ALT_BOOTDIR'), where is my building openjdk 7 jvm?

Answer (score 0):

That is ok
The hotspot was already complied success, the execution file is ~hotspot/build/linux_i486_compiler1/jvmg/hotspot